# Consider an isosceles triangle

Tags: geometry, circles, triangles

> Consider an isosceles triangle. Let $r$ be the radius of its circumscribed circle and $p$ the radius of its inscribed circle. Prove that the distance $d$ between the centres of these two circles is $d =\sqrt {r(r-2p)}$.

[image]

I could not get any idea to solve. However I have tried to make a figure (partially).

Comment: Your isosceles looks equilateral :P

Comment: @JaideepKhare,  consider it as isosceles

Comment: Well... Making good diagram is a skill which save you from misunderstanding the problem... So yes... Consider making a good diagram.

Comment: It's [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem_in_geometry).

Answer (score 5):

[image]

This is another masterpiece of Euler. This is general result of what you have asked.

Source: H.S.M. Coxeter and S.L. Greitzer- Geometry Revisited.

Comment: [+1] You have a good historical culture !

Comment: Why is $R^2-d^2 = LI \times IA$?

Comment: @rogerl think about power of point, that's what you need to know to conclude what you are asking, I will include answer to  that *why* of you don't understand it even after that hint.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following figure:

[image]

Using Euclid's theorem of sides in a right triangle one has
$$2r(r+d+p)=b^2=4r^2-a^2=4r^2-\left({2r\over r+d}\>p\right)^2\ .$$
It follows that
$$(r+d)^2(r+d+p)=2r\bigl((r+d)^2-p^2\bigr)=2r(r+d+p)(r+d-p)\ .$$
Removing the factor $r+d+p$ leads to
$$r^2+2rd+d^2=2r(r+d-p)\ ,$$
from which the claim immediately follows.

Comment: what does it mean 'Euclid's theorem of sides in a right triangle '?

Comment: It's the theorem that in a right triangle $b^2=cq$ where $c$ is the hypotenuse, $b$ a leg, and $q$ the projection of this leg onto the hypotenuse. The German word is "Kathetensatz".